# Пользователь забыл свой пароль. Как хешкод привести назад к нормальному виду и выдать пароль?

Tags: c#, безопасность, хеширование

Храню пароли пользователей в БД в хешированном виде. Использую для этого `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto`. Вот пример кода шифрования:

```
string password = "";
string hash = Crypto.HashPassword(password);
bool succes = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hash, password);
```

То есть я хеширую пароли, пишу в базу данных. И при авторизации пользователя могу проверить, ввёл ли он правильный пароль. Но что делать если пользователь забыл свой пароль? Как можно хешкод привести назад к нормальному виду и выдать пароль?

Comment: Никак, хранить пароли рядом :) На самом деле, надо генерировать новый пароль и отсылать забывчивому.

Answer (score 7):

По хэшу пароль восстановить нельзя, в том весь смысл безопасности. Вы не храните пароль, который могут украсть, а храните только хэш, который позволяет проверить правильность введенного пароля.

В случае когда пользователь забыл пароль, нужно иметь ссылку Забыли пароль? (Reset Password, сброс пароля). Тогда пользователь должен иметь возможность ввести новый пароль.

В веб приложениях это обычно делается через отсылку email на ящик пользователя со ссылкой на страницу, где можно ввести новый пароль.

Comment: demonplus а как же работают сервисы где когда ты забыл пароль тебе высылают на почту твой пароль? Они получается хранят и пароль в БД?

Comment: @Андрей нормальные сервисы отправляют новый пароль, а не старый

Comment: @Андрей не стоит пользоваться теми сервисами, которые отправляют старый пароль

Comment: Сервис должен генерить временный пароль, а потом пользователь вводит новый пароль. Хранение пароля, а не хэша противоречит всем требованиям безопасности